# Get overlib text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing my own grease monkey userscript.
I want to edit the overlib text using jquery.

This is what it looks like in HTML code:

```
<div class="expbar" onmouseover="return overlib('Some text',HAUTO,WIDTH,250,CAPTIONFONTCLASS,'action-caption',TEXTFONTCLASS,'overlibText overlibExtended',VAUTO,CAPTION,'POZIOM 44');">
```

I like to get the overlib popup text in a variable in jquery, "Some text".
I would also to be able to change that text.

Can not figure out how to do this.

This is what I can do:

```
var oldText = $(".expbar[onmouseover]").attr("onmouseover");
```

but then oldText contains whole "return overlib('Some text',HAUTO,WIDTH,250,CAPTIONFONTCLASS,'action-caption',TEXTFONTCLASS,'overlibText overlibExtended',VAUTO,CAPTION,'POZIOM 44');"

Please some help.

Comment: Try `var oldText = $(".expbar[onmouseover]").attr("onmouseover").split(',')[0].split('(')[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

```
GM_log("Level bar upgrade");
var oldAll = $(".expbar[onmouseover]").attr("onmouseover").split("'");
var oldText = oldAll[1];
oldText += "\\r\\r<br />Injection test";

var newAll = "";
for (var i = 0; i < oldAll.length; i++) {
    if(i == 1)
    {
        newAll += oldText;
    }
    else
    {
        newAll+=oldAll[i]
    }

    if(i != oldAll.length - 1)
    {
        newAll += "'";
    }
}
$(".expbar[onmouseover]").attr("onmouseover", newAll);
```